# org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession() Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to upgrade a project From Hibernate3/Spring to the current versions.

I have Hibernate 5.0.7 and Spring 4.2.4-Release. When I try to execute my code, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:328)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:239)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.getSession(HibernateInterceptor.java:153)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findFreightClassList(Unknown Source)
com.navajo.freight.web.controller.FreightRatesController.getFreightClassList(FreightRatesController.java:321)
```

I'm not using Maven, and I have very carefully checked my classpath. I'm  sure that there are no older versions of jar files or classes in the classpath.

My complete list of jar files is:

```
    activation-1.1.jar
    antlr-2.7.7.jar
    aopalliance.jar
    axiom-api-1.2.8.jar
    axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar
    axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar
    axis.jar
    axis2-adb-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-adb-codegen-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-ant-plugin-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-clustering-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-codegen-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-corba-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-fastinfoset-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-java2wsdl-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-jaxbri-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-jaxws-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-jibx-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-json-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-kernel-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-metadata-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-mtompolicy-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-saaj-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-spring-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-transport-local-1.5.1.jar
    axis2-xmlbeans-1.5.1.jar
    bcel-5.1.jar
    commons-beanutils.jar
    commons-codec-1.10.jar
    commons-collections-3.1.jar
    commons-discovery-0.2.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
    commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    commons-io-2.4.jar
    commons-lang-2.3.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
    commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    estes_transittime.jar
    files.lst
    geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
    hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar
    hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    httpcore-4.0.jar
    jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar
    jalopy-1.5rc3.jar
    jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
    javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
    javax-mail-1.5.4.jar
    JAXB2_20061211.jar
    jaxb-api-2.1.jar
    jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
    jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar
    jaxen-1.1.1.jar
    jaxrpc.jar
    jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
    jettison-1.0-RC2.jar
    jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar
    jibx-run-1.2.1.jar
    jstl.jar
    jta-1.1.jar
    log4j-1.2.15.jar
    mex-1.5.1.jar
    neethi-2.0.4.jar
    odfl.jar
    saaj.jar
    slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
    slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar
    smack-3.0.4.jar
    smackx-3.0.4.jar
    soapmonitor-1.5.1.jar
    spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-context-support-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-instrument-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-instrument-tomcat-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-oxm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-websocket-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
    sqljdbc4.jar
    standard.jar
    ups_freight.jar
    woden-api-1.0M8.jar
    woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar
    wsdl4j.jar
    wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
    xalan-2.7.0.jar
    xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
    xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
    xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
    xml-resolver-1.2.jar
    XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar
```

The tomcat installation is stock, with no additional Jars.

I've searched around, but I'm just not seeing any other asked questions that seem like the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the log, you still using hibernate 3 session factory

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:328)
```

change your session factory bean to use hibernate 5

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<!-- other configuration-->
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. That pushed me in the right direction. I had been trying that, but I got hung up by the deprecated hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor. I'll write another post about that issue.